# How to remove deal peak virus?

Tags: windows-7, virus

I have a computer that is kinda stumping me. It has something that has hijacked the browser with ads by dealpeak. 
I have checked browser extensions, hosts files, proxy servers, scanned with malwarebytes, MSE and spybot all to no result. Malwarebytes was set to scan for rootkits as well.

Also manually scanned over task manager to see if anything was out of the ordinary and did not see anything but did not do more than check the folder anything I did not recognize was running out of. I may have to go back and check all those that were in safe folders(ie c:\program file\lenovo).

Lenovo running windows 7. Can't give more specs because it is not right in front of me.

Comment: This may help: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/dealpeak-virus-removal/

Comment: Check in your programs. You may have unwittingly added a program while installing another program.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there was nothing recent in add/remove programs. Ill run the adwcleaner and HitmanPro from that list. Ive done all the rest to no avail.

Comment: You may want to look at and consider this: http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-anti-rootkit.aspx  . It once helped me out.